# Find only in directories n levels deep

Tags: find, regular-expression, php, exec

I use this command to find and run all istances of wp-cron.php I have for each site I have:

```
find /var/www/ -name 'wp-cron.php' -exec php -q "{}" \;
```

Since my websites tree is:

```
/var/www/site1/htdocs/WORDPRESS-FILES
/var/www/site2/htdocs/WORDPRESS-FILES
/var/www/site3/htdocs/WORDPRESS-FILES
/var/www/site4/htdocs/WORDPRESS-FILES
```

... I'd like to limit my command to just 3 or 4 levels inside /var/www/ to avoid wasting resources and time! How can I do that?

I'm on Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: With Gnu find: `-maxdepth`...

Answer (score 3):

If your `find` command has the `-maxdepth` option (Linux (GNU or BusyBox), FreeBSD, NetBSD, OSX):

```
find /var/www -maxdepth 3 -name wp-cron.php -exec php -q "{}" \;
```

If you want to run `wp-cron.php` files at an exact depth, you can use wildcards:

```
for x in /var/www/*/*/wp-cron.php; do
  php -q wp-cron.php
done
```

You can run

```
locate wp-cron.php
```

to quickly list all the files called `wp-cron.php` that existed the last time the [locate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix)) database was updated (typically nightly).